# C# - Post Large Contents or String with WebRequest

Tags: c#

i'm trying to POST large contents, about 13000 Characters. But i keep getting operation timed out. Changing the timeout doesn't help, because it takes a very long time.
Here's my code

```
string textToSpin = rtbOri.Text; //13000 Characters

            string post_data = "api_key=" + api_key + "&article=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textToSpin) + "&lang=" + lang;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(serviceUri);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            rtbSpin.AppendText(reader);
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Maybe an api constraint?

Comment: 13k characters is not big at all, that will be just something between 13Kb and 26Kb...

Comment: @Hackerman correct

Comment: Probably best guess would be contact the API provider and ask them about restrictions

Comment: @Gusman So now, what can i do? Should i use foreach lines?

Comment: @trailmax they providing unlimited characters, but they only give me simple sample code

Comment: Also if you are sending like just text, you don't need this `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`